# Convert to video timeline leaves me with too many layers

Tags: photoshop

I'm opening a gif in photoshop and it opens as a frame animation.

I hit Convert to video timeline and instead of converting to a single video layer it gives me X layers (x = # of animation frames)

I don't know what I did. Before this my ps would open the gifs as a video timeline

Answer (score -1):

Dont hit video timeline,,,,just in Create frame animation... 
screenshoot :
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9hvs.jpg)

there is two list ....

Comment: but i want a video timeline